# Can I listening port in native code on Android?

Tags: android, sockets, nanomsg

I have built nanomsg for android, so I have native lib (.so). And I try bind a socket (with Nanomsg).

I don't see any exceptions, but I can't connect to Socket.
If I create SocketServer (not from native code, not from C, but with just Android API) it works fine.

Is there some problem to listening to port from native code on Android?

Thanks.

Comment: No.  The Java code just eventually calls the native bind function like anything else.

Comment: BSD-style socket functions (`bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`, etc) work just fine in Android NDK code. Just make sure you app has adequate permissions assigned to it, like `android.permission.INTERNET`.